# How to change node's color using variable input with cytoscape in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cytoscape.js

I need to implement the following: User selects a variable and the colors of the nodes bodies change depending the variable selected.

For example I have the nodes :

```
[
{data:{id:'n0', var1:3,var2:10}},
{data:{id:''n1',var1:0,var4:20}},
]
```

I know you can use a mapper, mapData() to assign colors, but how do I update the style after rendering the component? Anyone have an example with layout.run() ? I am not exactly sure how to use it.

Comment: Those are 3 questions. For colors, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61078514/how-to-use-different-colors-to-mark-nodes-in-cytoscape-js. Also, you can run style updates and layout run after cy was initialized.